# Running SOCKS server on Raspi

Tags: networking, pi-4, hotspot

I have recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4B, I'm trying to use the SOCKS proxy.

**Setup:**

- Pi connected to the router via LAN/WiFi
- Pi acts an access point/hotspot
- Clients (PC, Laptop, TV ...) will be connected to the Pi's hotspot

(*Router is cheap and doesnot have any capabilities*, so whatever I do will be in Pi only)

**What I need**

Since it's little difficult to add the SOCKS settings to all devices, I want to route all the traffic through the SOCKS proxy for all the connected devices accordingly

Is it possible for this type of implementation?
I had come across the shadowsocks, where the browsers or the application has to be SOCKS-compliant.

[image]

Comment: Welcome -- but the brand of hardware is not very relevant to the question, which is why this is off-topic here.  What is relevant is the operating system with which you wish to do this.  The predominant one on the Pi ("Raspberry Pi OS", formerly Raspbian) is a Debian derivative, which is a very widely used GNU/Linux implementation.  If you wish to use that, you could ask on our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/); if you wish to use something else, ask in the appropriate place for whatever that is.

Comment: Other suitable options would be [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).  *Try not to emphasize the Pi angle too much* (preferably, leave it out and use eg. "a linux based AP and SOCKS server") or other people may be too distracted by this and send you back here.  If you can resist that temptation, you will get much better help with this question in those other places than here.